# Python Cryptography Generate Key from Password Error

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography

I'm trying a user-friendly encrypter and decrypter. Here is the code:

```
import base64
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

password_provided =input("Enter the Password: ")
password = password_provided.encode()
salt = os.urandom(16)
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA512(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password)) 
f=Fernet(key)
print(key)
print()
token=f.encrypt(b"secretpass")
print(token)
print()
password_provided =input("Enter the Password: ")
password = password_provided.encode()
salt =os.urandom(16)
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
    algorithm=hashes.SHA512(),
    length=32,
    salt=salt,
    iterations=100000,
    backend=default_backend()
)
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
print(key)
f=Fernet(key)
token=f.decrypt(token)
print(token)
```

But from the error i understand that it is due to diffrent salt. So how do i succeedconsidering the safety of user(not to use a default salt value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The salt is not a secret.

You should simply append/prepend it to the cipher text, and extract and re-use it for decryption.

You need to make a sort of mini-protocol for your app.

Always use cryptographically secure byte arrays for salts though, they must not be reused with the same key.

Additionally, don't forget to zero the vars holding the keys.

Comment: Ok. So i should store the salt with the file ? I plan to use this code to encrypt and decrypt files. And how do i change length=256 from length=32? I tried it and fernet raises an error.@Woodstock

Comment: cipher text? Whats that?

Comment: cipher text = encrypted data.    Yes Store the salt with the encrypted file.

Comment: @Wookstock and about the length?

Comment: 32 here is 32 bytes, thus 32*8bits = 256. It's already 256bit. btw avoid using this in production

Comment: if a hacker finds the salt(suppose) can he decrypt the file locked by 20 char password?

Comment: The salt is to ensure using the same password twice doesn’t result in the same key. It’s not to add entropy. Moreover, the KDF is intentionally “slow” Making it hard to crack.

Comment: One extra thing. You do have to use a strong password if you want it hard to crack. Strong == random and more than 10 chars